# ssh tunnel for 443

Tags: ssh, ssl, tunnel

I need get a file by a link (443), which is only possible  from server `B`.

I have 3 servers, (**A B C**).

It is possible to access server **B** and download this file by `wget` from server **C**.

```
wget https://NAME:PASS@DOMAIN.net/customerInfo/804-577823-10 --no-check-certificate
...
2021-06-18 16:18:01 (24,7 MB/s) - ‘804-577823-10’ saved [163/163]
```

From **A** to **B**, it is only allowed to use for port `22` (ssh), not port `443`.

I need to make a tunnel, which will go through from **A** to **B** via `22` and download the file from **C** via `wget` port `443`, exact the same way, as if I were on server **B**.

In short, I need a ssh tunnel from **A** to **B** and then I need to use port `443`, for apply/download the file on **C** via `wget` from **A**, same way as on **B**.

I tried, but no success.

```
ssh -L 4433:C:443 -Nf B
```

I tried even with proxy, but no success.

```
wget -e use_proxy=yes -e http_proxy=C https://NAME:PASS@DOMAIN.net/customerInfo/804-577823-10 --no-check-certificate
```

Is it possible?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

```
SERVER_A:443 -> ssh tunnel by port 22 through SERVER_B -> SERVER_C:443
```

So if I use on **SERVER_A** same link as on **SERVER_B**, I want to get file by `wget` from **SERVER_C**.

Simplest way is allow port `443` on **SERVER_C** for **SERVER_A**, but it is not possible in this case.

Allowed is only port `22` between **SERVER_A** and **SERVER_B**.

It is clearest now?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on who owns the servers in terms of permissions in order to determine what you are able to do. Also, what i do not quite understand is if this a one time download or you are in need of a permanent solution.

After reading your question I would go into server B with a secure shell.

```
$ ssh user@serverB
```

Then download the file from there. ( The point at the end is important)

```
$ scp -P 443 user@serverC:/path/to/file.txt  .
```

After this you can get send it to server A

```
$ scp file.txt user@serverA:~/
```

There are also more sophisticated solutions but it depends on your needs and freedom to act.

**Update**:

You can send a command to the server over ssh.

```
ssh user@serverB "wget your file at C"
```

You could do a double command like:

```
ssh user@serverB "wget your file @C:443  && scp file.txt you@serverA:~/"
```

But then you need to have serverB have his public certificates installed at serverA to go pass-wordless. The alternative is a 2 command script like explained above.

Comment: Hello, yes, I know, but I need direct access to this link/file which is on **C** server from **A** server, so I need to configure **A** server so that link from **C** server to be accessible on **A** server. Is it posstible to do it through ssh tunnel?

Comment: Do you own server B ?

Comment: Yes, I can do anything on server B, but not on C, so I can't allow access from server A to C directly via port 443.

Comment: @genderbee then you have to go the indirect way - scp it to server B, then scp from server B to server A.  If you don't own A or C then you really should be talking to their admins because they may not *want* A and C to have any file transfer.

Comment: @genderbee. Although I like the challenge of tunneling computers through the matrix, I really am wondering what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @rm- It is simple, I just want to configure server **A** to get file by `wget` link (port 443) same way, as I would be on server **B**, using by tunnel (or proxy?). Now, when I try `wget` on server **A**, connection is refused even ssh tunnel is up.

Comment: @rm- See question update please.

Comment: Yes I understand your question. Does my answer resolves your question? If not, you should look at other solutions then wget I guess. Hence my additional question. What are you REALLY trying to to? So we can help outside the scope of your question.

Comment: @rm- I have app based on PHP and this app is using wget call, so it is needed use by `wget`. Still no success.

Comment: Ok let's do this step by step. Can you wget your file when you are logged in server B? Look at:   https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#URL-Format

Comment: @rm- Yes, I can. Server B is prod, so it is possible to get link by port 443 from server C. Server A is test, and there is no possibility to get link by port 443 from server C. I have only port 22 allowed between server A and B. How can I make on server A (test) functional port 443 for needed link (server C) via tunnel through port 22?

Comment: Next step: Add in this wget command in the ssh command. Like in ssh user@serverB "wget command to server C" and execute on A. This should work. You can test the AB connection first with ssh@user "touch test.txt". There should be a new file "test.txt" present inside server B ( /home/user ) after this command.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do this in one command by piping the output through your SSH connection.  Assuming you are running this command *from* Server A, the following would work, I think.

```
$ ssh user@serverB "wget https://NAME:PASS@serverC/customerInfo/804-577823-10 --no-check-certificate -O -" > 804-577823-10.txt
```

This will connect to Server B, run the wget command to get content from Server C, and output it via STDOUT which is then captured in 804-577823-10.txt on Server A.

If you wanted to do this from a workstation outside of server A, you could also do the following:

```
$ ssh -J user@serverA user@serverB "wget https://NAME:PASS@serverC/customerInfo/804-577823-10 --no-check-certificate -O -" > 804-577823-10.txt
```

That will use server A as a jump box and then do the same thing as the previous command does.  I also use -A for agent forwarding, which you might be able to use if your credentials are shared across the servers, so...

```
$ ssh -A -J user@serverA user@serverB "wget https://NAME:PASS@serverC/customerInfo/804-577823-10 --no-check-certificate -O -" > 804-577823-10.txt
```

Lastly, if you want to actually create a tunnel from server A to server C on port 443, you can do the following:

```
$ sudo -i # Required to bind to port 443.
# ssh user@serverB -T -N -L 127.1.2.3:443:serverC:443 &
# wget https://NAME:PASS@127.1.2.3/customerInfo/804-577823-10 --no-check-certificate
# kill -INT %1
```

Or if you'd rather not use root, you'll need to bind to a port higher than 1024, typically people use 10443. So...

```
$ ssh user@serverB -T -N -L 127.1.2.3:10443:serverC:443 &
$ wget https://NAME:PASS@127.1.2.3:10443/customerInfo/804-577823-10 --no-check-certificate
$ kill -INT %1
```

Also, when you're accessing an HTTP server via a tunnel, it's possible the HTTP server may only know how to access the content you are looking for by a fully-qualified domain name (FQDN).  If so, you can add the parameter `--header='Host: www.example.com'` to your wget command to tell the server you are looking for content under that specific name.

Also note that you can bind to any 127.x.x.x address, which is useful if you're binding to a lot of different servers and you want to differentiate them more clearly.  Typically what I do is replace the first octet of the device I am binding the destination to with 127, so, something like 10.194.27.18 would become 127.194.27.18.  This will save you a lot of trouble if you're binding to multiple HTTP servers and want to prevent an overlap in cookies.

Hopefully this helps someone!  I know the question is a bit dated.